# Lower body fat loss using batte ropes?

Tags: weight-loss, cardio, hiit

So I understand that there's no such thing as spot fat reduction. The body loses fat all around when you're doing any type of cardio or compound movements.

Does that mean that battle ropes help me shed fat in my lower body too (things, quads,glutes). I do understand that glutes are engaged during battle ropes workout because you have to squat down. But is there a "fat loss" effect on the lower body as much as there is on the shoulders and back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in your question...

> I understand that there's no such thing as spot fat reduction

So you either don't understand or don't believe it. But that's the answer.

You will lose fat from your entire body no matter what cardio you do assuming your diet is correct and not just the exercise.

Comment: I do understand and I do believe what I said. It's just that lower body has no role to play in battle ropes so it just feels a little counter intuitive.

Comment: Again you're contradiction to the fact "no such thing as spot fat reduction" so it doesn't matter whether you're running or riding a bike. Your belly and arms etc will still lose fat. Same with battle ropes and legs losing fat

Comment: @user3508140 - Think of fat as a bank account. When you deposit money (i.e. eat food), it doesn't stay where you deposit it. It gets spread around by the bank to investments (or storage in fats case). When you need money, you go to the bank/atm and get some out. Same with bodyfat, when the body needs it it takes it. Every person has places the body prefers to store fat, and there is apocryphal lore that fat storage is on a last in first out type of system, but that is unproven. When the body needs energy, it just breaks down some fat from wherever it needs to.